# Howto configure Ipset to block entire countries IPs

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-14.04

I need to block some countries using ipset and iptables.

What I've done so far (create new ipset set 'geoblock'):

```
sudo ipset create geoblock hash:net,port
```

then I created the following script `/usr/sbin/ipsetfirewall.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
for IP in $(wget -O – http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/{cn,iq,af,ir,ae,sg,hk,kw,kg}.zone)
do
# ban everything – block countryX
sudo ipset add geoblock $IP
done
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7623766/4458531) I also tried:

```
wget -O – http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/{cn,iq,af,ir,ae,sg,hk,kw,kg}.zone --header "Referer: www.ipdeny.com"
```

and I tried this too (since I'm using ipv4)

```
wget -4 http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/{cn,iq,af,ir,ae,sg,hk,kw,kg}.zone
```

For all my tries I get this same error:

```
/usr/sbin$ sudo sh ipsetfirewall.sh
--2016-04-21 15:40:58--  http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/%7Bcn,iq,af,ir,ae,sg,hk,kw,kg%7D.zone
Resolving www.ipdeny.com (www.ipdeny.com)... 192.241.240.22
Connecting to www.ipdeny.com (www.ipdeny.com)|192.241.240.22|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-04-21 15:40:59 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

What's the problem?

Comment: You're making an HTTP call to `http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/{cn,iq,af,ir,ae,sg,hk,kw,kg}.zone` which fails. You need to be making individual calls for each country in your for loop.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks, now I can download using wget but when I type `sudo ipset list geoblock` my set is still not populated

Comment: add `set -x` as the first line of your script, and see exactly what is being executed?  That will help you debug.

Comment: Do you have brace expansion enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this script:

```
for country in cn tw in
do
    ipset destroy geoblock-$country > /dev/null 2>&1
    ipset create geoblock-$country hash:net
    for IP in $(wget -O - http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/$country.zone)
    do
        ipset add geoblock-$country $IP
    done
done
ipset save > /etc/ipset.rules
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably more efficient to grab all the zones

```
wget http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/all-zones.tar.gz
tar -xzf all-zones.tar.gz
```

Otherwise, one-at-a-time

```
for C in cn iq af ir ae sg hk kw kg ; do
   wget -4 http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/${C}.zone
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best guide I found so far.

https://mtxserv.com/vps-server/doc/how-to-block-ip-addresses-by-country